# unable to create event grid subscription based on storage_queue_endpoint

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-queues

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "<= 3.30.0"
        }
      }
      required_version = ">= 0.13"
    }
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
      subscription_id = var.subscription_id
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "current" {
      name = var.resource_group
    }
    
    #data "azurerm_storage_account" "default"{
    #  name=var.storage_account_name
    # resource_group_name=var.storage_account_resource_group
    #}
    
    #resource "azurerm_storage_queue" "default" {
    #name=var.storage_queue_name
    #storage_account_name=data.azurerm_storage_account.default.name
    #}
    
    module "storage-account" {
      source                     = "git@github.com:procter-gamble/terraform-azure-storage-account.git?ref=v4.0.0"
      count                      = var.existing_storage_account ? 0 : 1
      subscription_id            = data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id
      resource_group             = data.azurerm_resource_group.current.name
      resource_name              = var.storage_account_name
      access_groups              = []
      resource_tags              = var.resource_tags
      account_tier               = var.storage_account_tier
      access_tier                = var.storage_access_tier
      replication_type           = var.storage_replication_type
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = var.storage_virtual_network_subnet_ids
      create_private_dns         = false
      enable_private_endpoint    = false
      queues                     = var.queues
      ip_rules                   = var.ip_rules
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "default" {
      for_each                             = { for event in var.event_grid : event.name => event }
      name                                 = each.value.name
      event_delivery_schema                = lookup(each.value, "event_delivery_schema", null)
      advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled = lookup(each.value, "advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled", null)
      scope                                = data.azurerm_resource_group.current.id
    
      dynamic "storage_queue_endpoint" {
        for_each = lookup(each.value, "storage_queue_endpoint", "false") == "true" ? [1] : []
        content {
          storage_account_id                    = join(",",[module.storage-account[0].id])
          queue_name                            = "test"
          queue_message_time_to_live_in_seconds = lookup(each.value, "queue_message_time_to_live_in_seconds", null)
        }
      }
     depends_on=[module.storage-account]
    **

> }
```

Planning to create azure event grid subscription with
storage_queue_endpoint. I'm able to create storage account & queue but while access endpoint toughing an below error

> ╷ │ Error: waiting for Event Subscription: (Name "evengridtest01" /
> Scope
> "/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/********"): Code="Endpoint validation" Message="Destination endpoint not found.
> Resource details: resourceId:
> /subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/*******/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tfteststgacc009.
> Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation. Activity
> id:7a4d548e-53ba-4530-a93e-8c2d48aad183, timestamp: 2/17/2023 3:54:27
> PM (UTC)." │ │   with
> azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription.default["evengridtest01"], │   on
> main.tf line 50, in resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription"
> "default": │   50: resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription"
> "default" { │ ╵

Answer (score 0):

I tried the similar code like yours :

Code:

```
resource azurerm_storage_account "storage-account" {
 count                      = var.existing_storage_account ? 0 : 1
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS" 
  access_tier                = var.storage_access_tier
 
}


resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "default" {
  for_each                             = { for event in var.event_grid : event.name => event }
  name                                 = each.value.name
  event_delivery_schema                = lookup(each.value, "event_delivery_schema", null)
  advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled = lookup(each.value, "advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled", null)
  scope                                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  
 
 dynamic "storage_queue_endpoint" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "storage_queue_endpoint", "false") == "true" ? [0] : [1]
    content {
      storage_account_id                    = join(",", [azurerm_storage_account.storage-account[0].id])
      queue_name                            = "test"
      queue_message_time_to_live_in_seconds = lookup(each.value, "queue_message_time_to_live_in_seconds", null)
    }
  }
  
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.storage-account ]
}

│ Error: waiting for Event Subscription: (Name "subscription2" / Scope "/subscriptions/xxxe87ca71c/resourceGroups/xxx"): Code="Endpoint validation" Message="Destination endpoint not found. Resource details: resourceId: /subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mykastorgeaccount. Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation.
```

[image]

For that , there must be existing storage account present before creating event grid subscription to a destinantion endpoint.

```
az eventgrid topic create --name xxx --location xxx --resource-group xxx

az eventgrid event-subscription create --name <subscription name> --resource-group <resource group name> --topic-name <xxx> --endpoint <endpoint-url>
```

Create an Event Grid event subscription for each storage queue endpoint

Then check the storage account is existing

```
az storage account show --name <storage account name> --resource-group <resource group name>
```

[image]

Then as the endpoint is pointed successfully, the event grid subscription can be created.

[image]

The following code worked for me:

---

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "existing_storage_account" {
  description = "Flag indicating whether an existing storage account should be used or a new one created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "Name of the storage account to be created"
  type        = string
  default     = "mykastorgeaccount"
}


variable "storage_account_tier" {
  description = "Tier of the storage account (Standard or Premium)"
  type        = string
  default     = "Standard"
}

variable "storage_access_tier" {
  description = "Access tier of the storage account (Hot or Cool)"
  type        = string
  default     = "Hot"
}

variable "storage_replication_type" {
  description = "Replication type of the storage account (LRS, GRS, RAGRS, or ZRS)"
  type        = string
  default     = "LRS"
}
```

**Main.tf**

```
resource azurerm_storage_account "storageaccount" {
 count                      = var.existing_storage_account ? 1 : 0
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  access_tier                = var.storage_access_tier
}

resource "azurerm_storage_queue" "example" {
  name                 = "examplestq"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount[0].name
}





resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "default" {
  for_each                             = { for event in var.event_grid : event.name => event }
  name                                 = each.value.name
  event_delivery_schema                = lookup(each.value, "event_delivery_schema", null)
  advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled = lookup(each.value, "advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled", null)
  scope=azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount[0].id
  dynamic "storage_queue_endpoint" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "storage_queue_endpoint", "false") == "true" ? [1] : [0]
    content {
      storage_account_id                    = join(",", [azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount[0].id])
      queue_name                            = azurerm_storage_queue.example.name
       
      queue_message_time_to_live_in_seconds = lookup(each.value, "queue_message_time_to_live_in_seconds", null)
    }
  }
  
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount ]
}
```

[image]

**Reference :**

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventgrid_event_subscription

Comment: I added dependence as well like  **depends_on=[module.storage-account]**, but still throughing same error.

verified storage account /queue through az cli and its shows exists.

Comment: can you check your account by command:  `az account show`   .If not already set, set your subscription `az account set --subscription <subscription_id>`

Comment: Subscription is set already in my local.
Is 404 status code message related authorization/permission issue.?

Comment: check if required provider exists ,`az provider show --namespace Microsoft.EventGrid` . 404 means the resource is not found. Check if you have multiple subscriptions and logged into desired subscription .